# Complex TreeView with stepper Xamarin Forms,Syncfusion

Tags: list, xamarin.forms, treeview, syncfusion, stepper

I am trying to accomplish the following design. I see several elements here and I would like to have a different idea of how it can be done.
any examples will help a lot.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the UI provided, you can achieve the required UI by using the SfAccordion control. You can customize the ItemTemplate, which can be specified for each item instead of the SfTreeView. I have attached the documentation and sample for your reference.

Also, the accordion control allows content to be organized in a collapsible, vertically stacked list of items. Each item can also be expanded to reveal the content associated with that item.

UG Link: https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/accordion/getting-started

KB Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11437/how-to-work-with-accordion-using-c-in-xamarin-forms-sfaccordion